# Anypoint Studio - Mule Debug - "Stacktrace"

Tags: debugging, mule, anypoint-studio

In Anypoint Studio breakpoints can be set in Subflows.

Using these the processing can be suspended, the message and the flow variables can be inspected.

I was wondering though... is it possible to find out how we ended up in the given subflow? Can we access some kind of "flow-call/reference stacktrace"? Is is possible to find out how we ended up in the given suflow?

For example in the following flow the "appendContentSubFlow" is referenced by appendContent and "appendContent Again":

[image: Screenshot]

How can we tell; which reference lead to the current hit of the breakpoint st in the subflow?

The "ByteArray to String" processing step is marked with dashed-borders, since the set breakpoint has stopped the execution in this step... however; the calling/referencing step is not marked at all.

First I thought, that this could be because I am using a subflow, but the same thing happens, when I am using a private-flow. Only the current processing step is marked and no "stacktrace-like" information is available.

Is there a way to find out where the call to the subflow/private-flow came from? Is the only way to do this to step to the next processing-step until we return to the calling flow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment this is not possible in Anypoint studio. You can't see the "Flow-Call" Stacktrace in the debugger, but you can achieve similar results using one of the following "workarounds":

- *You can use Search* -> File Search and search your subflow name, use *.xml as filename pattern -> this will return mule configs that contains the calling flow. if multiple calling flow found you can add breakpoints to each to find which of the flow triggers the call.
- or you can just *add breakpoints to all possible calling flow*.

Comment: These are useful tricks. Thank you very much, but this is not exactly what I want to achieve - these are rather workrounds to achieve something similar. Do you think, that the functionality I am looking for is not available in this form, as described in the question, in the current version of Anypoint Studio?